# Dropdown in pagination

Tags: php

I want to add dropdown in pagination so that if there is more then 10 pages it will be stored in dropdown so that any one can select any page from it.

Here is my php code which show this output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11........... 100

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_data`"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='View.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "&nbsp;<a href='View.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
echo "&nbsp;<a href='View.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> ";//Goto last page
```

Output i want :
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 dropdown(contains all pages 11 to 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it with php using your php code. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_data`"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a  href='View.php?page=1'>".'FIRST <<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
  { 
    if($total_pages<=10)
       {
         echo "&nbsp;<a style='color:#333;' href='View.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
       }
else
{
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) 
     { 
        echo "&nbsp;<a style='color:#333;' href="View.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
     };
    echo "<select class='mySelectBox' onchange='location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>";
     for ($i=11; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
     { 
            echo "<option value= View.php?page=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
     };
      echo "</select>";
}
}; 
echo "&nbsp;<a href='View.php?page=$total_pages'>".'........>> LAST'."</a> "; // Goto last page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_data`"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='View.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  
$array = [];
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        $array[$i] = "<a href='View.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>"; 
}; 
echo "&nbsp;<a href='View.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> ";//Goto last page
```

Add all the page informations in array and then later populate the dropdown with an array I have changed the for loop code only ... you just popultae your dropdown with the $array;

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: @Shalini in for loop I have added all page links in an array which you echo.... Then I told you to add that $array in dropdown that's it :) let me know if you don't understand

Comment: Apologised but not able to add dropdown. it was not clickable. Will you please help me more...

Comment: @Shalini sure just give me some time

Comment: @Shalini you have to use javascript then please refere this [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lisawoll/2004/08/19/creating-a-drop-down-list-that-links-to-other-pages/]

Comment: Is it not possible with php, without adding any javascript code??

Comment: @Shalini No its not ... If you want to use redirect in dropdown the you should go with JS :(